# How to color every bar in google timeline chart?

Tags: charts, google-visualization, react-google-charts

I have read some other answers here and accordingly added the `role` property but it did not work.

```
<Chart
  width={'500px'}
  height={'300px'}
  chartType="Timeline"
  loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
  data={[
    [
      { type: 'string', id: 'President' },
      { type: 'date', id: 'Start' },
      { type: 'date', id: 'End' },
      {type: 'string', role: 'style'}
    ],
    ['Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4), 'gold'],
    ['Adams', new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4), 'color: #ccc'],
    ['Jefferson', new Date(1801, 2, 4), new Date(1809, 2, 4), 'gold'],
  ]}
  options={{
    showRowNumber: true,
  }}
  rootProps={{ 'data-testid': '1' }}
/>
```

refer: https://react-google-charts.com/timeline-chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the timeline chart, the style role will only work when used as the third column.

so you will also need to add the second column for bar label.
but you can use `null` values for that column, if needed...

```
<Chart
  width={'500px'}
  height={'300px'}
  chartType="Timeline"
  loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
  data={[
    [
      { type: 'string', id: 'President' },
      { type: 'string', id: 'Bar' },        // <-- add bar label here...
      { type: 'string', role: 'style' },    // <-- add style role here...
      { type: 'date', id: 'Start' },
      { type: 'date', id: 'End' }
    ],
    ['Washington', null, 'gold', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4)],
    ['Adams', null, '#ccc', new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
    ['Jefferson', null, 'gold', new Date(1801, 2, 4), new Date(1809, 2, 4)],
  ]}
  options={{
    showRowNumber: true,
  }}
  rootProps={{ 'data-testid': '1' }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it! I sorted the bars according the role attribute.
I used the role property in data structure.

const data = [ [ { type: "string", id: "Phases" },{ type: "string", id: "Name" }, { type: 'string', role: 'style' }, { type: "date", id: "Start" },       { type: "date", id: "End" } ]];

<Chart chartType="Timeline" data={[...data, ...firstArray, ...secondArray]} width="100%" height={setChartHeight((firstArray.length+secondArray))} options={{ timeline: { } }} />

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW9Dc.png)

This is my second answer on Stackoverflow. I still don't understand how to indent the code in the answer.